# Reading first element of each column and then the entire row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file

I have a csv file, like this:

```
Account     Email       User_Id     User Type   Base Role   Last Login
123456  x@proton.com    111111         inter      user         7
7891011 y@proton.com    222222         inter      user         6
121314  z@proton.com    333333         inter      user         5
```

and there will be 50 other rows like this. Each account can have multiple users. and also the same account can be listed on the file multiple times.
I have to create a new csv file for each account.
For each account, I have to select the entire row and copy its contents.
How do I go about this?
How do I select:

```
for each account number
   if a csv file for this account does not exist already
       create a new file
   copy the entire now and paste it in the new csv file
```

I can create a new csv file with this:

```
with open("test.csv") as fp
```

but I am stuck with how do I go about selecting each account number and then copying and pasting the contents of that row in a new file. I am new to Python. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas in python.

```
import pandas as pd
```

if u have DataFrame -> its ok

if u don't u can use this line to convert your CSV to the DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')
```

now you can select your data using DataFrame functions like this.

```
new_df = df.loc[df['Account'] == 123456]
```

new_df is a DataFrame too. you can save your result DataFrame using :

```
new_df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

you can do it for each of the account numbers using these codes :

```
for i in df['Account'] :

    new_df = df.loc[df['Account'] == i]
    
    # you can use list of file path for saving results   
    new_df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Comment: How do I do this for each of the account numbers?

Comment: I will edit this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with a `csv` module by default

```
import csv

def get_firsts(csvfile, skip_first=True):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        if skip_first:
            _ = next(data)
        firsts = [row[0] for row in data]
    return firsts
```

This returns a list with only the first element of each row, you can get rid of the first if it's a column name.

Comment: What is the `if skip_first:
            _ = next(data)` code doing?

Comment: @winterlyrock if the first line is the labels, you usually want to split that. It helps if you're doing some logic on columns. You can also assign the _ to a useful list and return it

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which provides a lot of data processing primitives, including aggregations and a helper for CSV files:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

dialect = Table.csv_dialect(delimiter="\t")
# read the input file
table = Table.from_csv("input_1.csv", header=True, dialect=dialect)
# remember the header
header = table.columns

# prepare a converter to group by first column (we could work with dicts, but
# it is slower), aggregate by storing rows in arrays
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate({"account": c.item(0), "rows": c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.this())})
    .gen_converter()
)

# perform aggregation
data_by_accounts = converter(table.into_iter_rows(list))

# write files
for data in data_by_accounts:
    Table.from_rows(data["rows"], header=header).into_csv(
        "account_{}.csv".format(data["account"]), dialect=dialect
    )
```